# Lightning problems

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, export, settings

I am trying to render an animation but when I export a frame to check that everything is okay, the output is really dark, which doesn´t make sense for me.

What im using is sky texture for enviromental lightning and a light recreating the sun, but I thing that the first one isn´t working. I don´t know if it has something to do with the render settings or the compositing tab.

Also, the dimensions of the objects in the scene are quite big but I guess it shouldn´t really matter with the enviromental lightning.

[image: This is the background]

[image: The preview]

[image: The final render]

[image: More settings]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DJTvIFrOCIgNC5JThAuLhY46x8Q_0-eq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: pls show us your compositing nodes - or even better -provide a blend file (if you don't wanna provide your model, just delete it, it isnt important for the lighting)

Comment: please check these items here:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWxZa.png as you can see, there won't be shown in viewport, but they will be rendered. You should keep both the same if you wanna the the same result in viewport + render. So either eye and cam should be checked or both unchecked for each item.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: @Chris I know that, eventhough they are off or on the scene doesn´t change. The main issue here is, why the viewport lightning doesn´t match the output? how can I solve that? It triggers me beacause its really dark when rendering. Anyway thank you

Comment: @GAlas: as you can see here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk5DR.gif it makes a HUGE difference if they are on or off. So either you are a complete Blender beginner or you didn't check that at all in rendered view

Comment: @Chris Yoo now it works, thank you so much. Btw I also moved everything to another side and now the render has a lot of light. Thank you for real